# Initialize a multiple levels hash in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variable-initialization

So I have some codes look like the following:

```
@foo ||= {}
@foo[:bar] ||= {}
@foo[:bar][:baz] ||= {}
```

I am not concerning the performance, but the cleanness. Is there a more beautiful way or better way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{:bar => {:baz => {}}}.merge(@foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have is a good, terse way of writing the code, but below is another way I thought of to do the same thing. It'll still do the job, if you'd prefer to be more verbose:

```
if @foo.nil?
    @foo = { :bar => { :baz => {} } }
else if @foo[:bar].nil?
    @foo[:bar] = { :baz => {} }
else if @foo[:bar][:baz].nil?
    @foo[:bar][:baz] = {}
end
```

or

```
if !@foo
    @foo = { :bar => { :baz => {} } }
else if !@foo[:bar]
    @foo[:bar] = { :baz => {} }
else if !@foo[:bar][:baz]
    @foo[:bar][:baz] = {}
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but I would rather want a more simple way to do it......